# Django admin edit inline objects on form clean

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have following model:

```
class ProjectBudget(models.Model):
```

It has a form and inline:

```
class ProjectBudgetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):  
    form = ProjectBudgetForm
    inlines= [ProjectSpentsInline]

class ProjectSpentsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ProjectSpents
```

On a form i have a field `file`. From this file i want populate inline object `ProjectSpents` values:

```
class ProjectBudgetForm(ModelForm):
    file  = forms.FileField

    def clean_file(self):
        parse file then populate inline model objects ProjectSpents....
```

The problem is that i want to edit inline values of ProjectSpents from clean_file,  but there is a problem, because queryset is already fullfilled before clean_file and new inline values are not 
shoiwing. Maybe there is another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the model admin method [`save_formset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_formset). You can iterate through the formset instances to delete the existing inlines, then access `form.cleaned_data['file']` and create the new related instances.

Comment: Alasdair, thank you for the right direction, but i'v made a little bit different solution. The problem is Django 1.3 doesn't return old instances on formset.save(commit=False). I'v been overiten inline formset and  _should_delete_form(self, form) method to mark inline value for deleting.